# Can a cat be a co-author in academic paper?

Tags: publications, ethics, authorship, copyright, academic-life

One of the most famous cat physicians must be [F. D. Willard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F._D._C._Willard), who co-authored many physical papers.

My question is simple:

Is it academically correct to have a cat/dog as a co-author of a paper, in principle? 
Does it correspond to the academic code of ethics? 
Does the author has to be a natural human?

Comment: If you are an established professor it has a very different impact than if you are at the beginning of your career. It won't help you to appear foolish if you are just starting out.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding whether or not all authors must be human, the answer seems to be no.

Combinatorist [Doron Zeilberger](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doron_Zeilberger), for example, has published many papers jointly with Salosh B. Ekhad (his name for his computer).

Comment: Shalosh even has a paper without a human co-author. From MathSciNet: MR1235178  Ekhad, Shalosh B. A short, elementary, and easy, WZ proof of the Askey-Gasper inequality that was used by de Branges in his proof of the Bieberbach conjecture. Conference on Formal Power Series and Algebraic Combinatorics (Bordeaux, 1991). Theoret. Comput. Sci. 117 (1993), no. 1-2, 199–202.